# Conversion of String into Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using some built in functions which is taking some arrays as input. Now I have value

```
String network=[{"GUID":"a","Type":"WiFi","WiFi":{"AutoConnect":true,"Passphrase":"12345678","SSID":"Free PTCL unlimited"}},{"GUID":"b","Type":"WiFi","WiFi":{"AutoConnect":true,"Passphrase":"12345678","SSID":"Free PTCL unlimited"}}]
```

Actually it is like an array but when i input this value the compiler say the function requires an array value. Now what i need to to convert this string into array

Comment: You should start by getting a correct string, that will actually compile.

Comment: This is just invalid Java syntax. Java cannot parse JSON syntax directly. You need to deserialize it from a string using a JSON-parser like Jackson or Gson.

Comment: Also, if you want it to be a string, you need to add quotes (`"`). Like `String network = "...value...";`.

Comment: I think u didn't get my question

Comment: I have an arraylist which stores values but u know due to encapsulation the function cannot read the values of arraylist so i am converting it into json using gson

Comment: but my function needs array when i pass arraylist my function cannot read the values of arraylist to encapsulation

Comment: as you mentioned that function need an array, not a list of array. You can simply declare and access particular element (this is a single array reside within list of array) inside list of array by index.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax in wrong...

when you do `String network=...` you declare network as a `String` not as an array

arrays in java must be declared/initialized like:

```
String[] network = {"a", "b", "c"};
```